# Uploading images on Facebook in iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with an ioS application in which i have to upload images on Facebook, so i am adding Facebook-SDK and it works fine. Currently it works well for my account , but when i upload from another account it will authenticate but when i try to upload it gives me error :

```
Error: {
    "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey" = "<FBSession: 0xa547730, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x2051e8, appID: 108735182, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0xa54bff0>, expirationDate: 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-10-15 12:03:28 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(\n    \"basic_info\",\n    installed,\n    \"user_location\",\n    \"public_profile\",\n    email,\n    \"user_birthday\",\n    \"user_friends\"\n)>";
    "com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" = 400;
    "com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey" =     {
        body =         {
            error =             {
                code = 10;
                message = "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action";
                type = OAuthException;
            };
        };
        code = 400;
    };
}
```

there is no issue with the video upload ,but image upload gives this above error.
In app setting i dont have iPhone Store ID so i leave it vacant.

Answer (score 1):

There might be few reasons for that. The first might be that you didn't request additional permission to publish posts on FB (publish_actions permission). In order to publish a post on Facebook you need to request from the user the publish permissions and only then the user can have sufficient permissions to make the action. 
You read more on :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share